# Why the Custom role In Azure AD is assigned to all the group?

Tags: azure-active-directory

In our tenant, we have a custom Role For groups with the below permissions.

microsoft.directory/groups/create,

microsoft.directory/groups/delete,

microsoft.directory/groups/members/read

microsoft.directory/groups/members/update

microsoft.directory/groups/owners/read

microsoft.directory/groups/owners/update.

From when the custom role is created it was automatically applied to all the groups in our tenant.

Why the custom role is applied automatically to all the groups in our tenant?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one new **custom role** in my tenant with **same** permissions as you like below:

[image]

I enabled **below option** while creating Azure AD groups in my tenant:

[image]

I have below Azure AD groups that are **eligible** for role assignment:

[image]

> Why the custom role is applied automatically to all the groups in our
> tenant?

I think you are checking **Roles and Administrators** tab of those groups, that displays ***eligible*** roles to assign in which **`custom role`** appears like below:

*Srigroup01:*
[image]

*Srigroup02:*
[image]

To know whether role is assigned to group or not, you need to check **Assigned roles** tab like below:

*Srigroup01:*
[image]

*Srigroup02:*
[image]

You can also check **Assignments** under your custom role like below:

[image]

Select **Add assignment** if you want to apply this role on specific groups like below:

[image]

When I checked **Assigned roles** tab in that group, custom role is assigned successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: How you created custom role, via Portal or using any automation like Powershell or CLI?

Comment: By the same as u mentioned above in portal